# Скачивание файлов с помощью shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Пишу скрипт, который получит параметром страницу в интрнете. Скрипт должен её скачать, найти на ней все эмеилы (я думаю, поиска по @ достаточно) и сохранить в документ. Потом найти все ссылки (я так понимаю можно сделать это поиском слова href) и скачать все те страницы. Проделать на них тоже самое. Да, скрипт скорее всего будет бесконечным, но это ок. Не знаю как это реализовать, не особо комфортно в такой ситуации, так как во всех прошлых вопросах я просил помочь конкретно с моим кодом. Буду рад как готовому решению, так и любому совету/подсказке.

Comment: По-хорошему, это на шелле практически очень трудно реализовать. Вам надо распарсить XML, и уже в узлах искать (причём надо отличать теги и текст). Помимо прочего текст на странице может быть в заэскейпленом виде, то есть надо согласно заголовку HTML / XML читать кодировку и декодировать. Ниже ответ - не ответ, а так.

Comment: @AS3Master это задачу уже решили на питоне в библиотеке beautifulsoupe https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 3):

примерный «костяк» программы:

```
main() { # первый и единственный параметр — url
  file=получить_уникальное_имя_для_временного_файла
  wget -qO "$file" "$1"
  grep "регулярное выражение для извлечения email" "$file" >> файл-с-email-ами
  grep "регулярное выражение для извлечения ссылок" | while read url
    do main "$url"
  done
  rm "$file"
}
```

про реализацию регулярных выражений и получение уникального имени для временного файла — спрашивайте с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: Не совсем понял, "получить_уникальное_имя_для_временного_файла" просто генерация случайного имени? Например filename + в конце i, где i увеличивается по счётчику?

Comment: да, можно и так. сложность лишь со счётчиком.